# sql order by and group by

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have some problems with a sql request:

```
SELECT DISTINCT b . * 
FROM follow a 
INNER JOIN position b 
  ON a.user_id = b.follow_id 
INNER JOIN referent_follow c 
  ON a.user_id = c.follow 
WHERE c.referent = 14 
GROUP BY b.follow_id 
ORDER BY b.date DESC
```

This request works. I add a group by because I don't want the same follow_id in the result. This works I never have the same follow_id in the reponse but for each follow_id the request return the first one and I'd like to get the last one (order by date desc)

Adding order by date desc at this end this order the final result and not the follow_id to chose

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return the `max(date)`, then you can use a subquery:

```
SELECT b.* 
FROM follow a 
INNER JOIN position b 
  ON a.user_id = b.follow_id 
INNER JOIN
(
    select max(date) MaxDate, follow_id
    from position
    group by follow_id
) b1
    on b.follow_id = b1.follow_id
    and b.date = b1.MaxDate
INNER JOIN referent_follow c 
  ON a.user_id = c.follow 
WHERE c.referent = 14 
ORDER BY b.date DESC
```

The subquery will return the `max(date)` for each `follow_id` and then you join that result back to the `position` table to return the remaining data from the `position` table.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will work.

```
select JustTheFieldsYouNeed, max(datefield) maxdate
from follow a join position b a.user_id = b.follow_id 
join referent_follow c on a.user_id = c.follow 
where c.referent = 14 
group by JustTheFieldsYouNeed
```

If you really do need every field from position, type them out.